# QT .png File not showing up on screen

Tags: c++, image, qt, png

All I appear to get is a white screen when I compile and run my project. The image does exist, and the images folder is in my project's root directory. All I'm trying to do is load a simple  image onto the screen. Is there anything specific I'm missing here?

**Code**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QDir>
#include "chronos_main_window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QDir dir;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    //ChronosMainWindow window;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap(dir.relativeFilePath("images\\ozone_sprite.png"))); //images folder is located in project root dir
    scene.addItem(&item);
    //window.show();
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: yes you are missong the question, and you are missing the resources file .qrc that handles the Qt resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in your code:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem item(
                     QPixmap(dir.relativeFilePath(":/images/ozone_sprite.png")));
```

In resource.qrc(if you don't have it, then right click on your project. Add new.. -> Qt -> Qt Resource file), then open it with plain text editor:

```
<RCC>
<qresource>
    <file>images/ozone_sprite.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you can load a QPixmap from the same directory of the application

`QPixmap("./image.png")`

else you can load the image from a qrc file:

`QPixmap(":path")` 
 
path depends on how you made the qrc file
it s difficult to me explaining how to do qrc file because i m not english. but you can find a lot of documentation on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try declare `QDir` object after creation instance of `QApplication`